# NSPredicate strings greater comparision

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nspredicate

I am trying to compare if one NSString is "greater" than other NSString and I am stuck. Actually, my NSString contains a date and want to get all these objects that are greater than it.
I know I should convert it to date, but I want to keep it as NSString.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
[string1 compare:otherString] == NSOrderedDescending
```